# Pre-Processor C Macro Syntax

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, conditional-operator

I am trying to understand the Pre-Processor syntax. Its really simple line of code that either returns "ON" or "OFF". However I am utterly confused as to what exactly the condition is?

I understand C's conditional statement as follows:

```
? x : y
```

If Condition ? return - replace? x : or y either way this line of code is as follows:

```
#define ONOFF(a) ((a) ? "ON" : "OFF")
```

I don't understand what condition must be met here? Is the condition that a has to be something other than null?

Comment: By "statement" do you mean "expression"? Those are two very different things.

Comment: Just like you can write `if(a)` in your C++ syntax - it means that `a` must be [truthy](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/3483/). Falsy would be only `false`, `0` or `NULL` (which is similar to `(void*)0`).

Comment: The type of the 1st operand has nothing to do with the types of the 2nd and 3rd operands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`True` and `Flase` can be more perfectly presented as `1` or `0` . As I can see you have declared

```
#define ONOFF(a) ((a) ? "ON" : "OFF")
```

Your condition here is `(a)`, which is`true`if the value of`a` is non zero and false if `a`is 0

Which means in your program, if you write

```
int a=1; 
char *str;
str=ONOFF(a);
```

The substitution which takes place is

```
 int a=1;  
 char *str;
 str=((a) ? "ON" : "OFF")// here a=1
```

Since here `a` is `1` and 
`1` is true and str gets the value `ON`. If `a` were 0, then str would get the value `OFF`

Answer (score 0):

To add a bit of context here, the first operand of the conditional operato has to be of *scalar type*. Now, from chapter §6.2.5, of `C11`,

> Arithmetic types and pointer types are collectively called *scalar types*.

So, for the conditional expression,

- any non-zero value gets evaluated as TRUE and zero (`0`) is evaluated as FALSE.
- (In case of pointers) a `NULL` is FALSE, any non-`NULL` is TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

The condition is that `a` has to evaluate to `true`. In c, that means that `a` must be an expression that is non-zero.

If `a` is a pointer type, `NULL` is `false` and any other value is `true`.

If `a` is an integer type, `0` is `false` and any other value is `true`.

If `a` is a floating point type, `0` is `false` and any other value is `true`.

If `a` is a `struct` or a `void` type you will get a compile error.

Answer (score 0):

Preprocessor macros do *textual substitution*, so `a` is not a variable -- it's just a placeholder for whatever text is in the parentheses when the macro is *used*.

You could use it for checking pointers are not null like this:

```
printf("%s\n", ONOFF(ptr));
printf("%s\n", ONOFF(ptr != null));  // This is the same
```

Or any other type of condition you like:

```
printf("%s\n", ONOFF(a > b));
printf("%s\n", ONOFF(a && b));
printf("%s\n", ONOFF(a == 1 || c == 4));
printf("%s\n", ONOFF(somefunction() != 0));
printf("%s\n", ONOFF((a == b && c == d) || (a == c && b == d));
printf("%s\n", ONOFF(my_bool_value));
```